# Angular component: On ngModelChange it moves to the next control and duplicates input

Tags: angular15

I have this component:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-number-inputs',
  templateUrl: './number-inputs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./number-inputs.component.scss']
})
export class NumberInputsComponent {
  numbers: number[] = Array(5).fill(0);

  @Output() numbersChanged = new EventEmitter<number[]>();

  onInputChange(newValue: number) {
    this.numbersChanged.emit(this.numbers);
  }

  getNumbers(){
    return this.numbers;
  }
}




<h3>VALUES FOR THE AVERAGE</h3>
<div *ngFor="let number of numbers; let i = index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="numbers[i]" type="number" min="0" (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)">
</div>
```

But still when I type a number, it goes to the next input and duplicate the value.

For example
input 1 I type 1
It goes to input 2 and types 1
input 2 I type a 2 and I get 12 because I had the previous 1
It goes to input 3 and types 12

And so on 12345

and so on

I tried also using the (input) event but it changes nothing
Finally I also tried using index to update the property directly:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="numbers[i]" type="number" min="0" (ngModelChange)="onInputChange(i, $event)">

  onInputChange(index: number, newValue: number) {
this.numbers[index] = newValue;
this.numbersChanged.emit(this.numbers);
}
```

to no avail